# Time format in XSLT 2.0

Tags: function, xslt

I worked with xslt 2.0 and Java( Saxon-HE ).Saxon-HE do not support xslt date-time format.I have current-date()  and current-time() functions and I need them in the following format time(17:31), date(03/06).Please help me and give any suggestion hot to do it.Thanks a lot of

Comment: Saxon-HE does support the full repertoire of XSLT 2.0 functions and operators for date and time handling, including the format-date() and format-time() functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below tranformation:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="test">
    <xsl:variable name="currenttime" select="current-dateTime()" as="xs:dateTime"/> 
    <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime($currenttime,'[H]')"/><xsl:text>:</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime($currenttime,'[m]')"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime($currenttime,'[M]')"/><xsl:text>/</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime($currenttime,'[D]')"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```